# AB testing for Recommender models

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, predictive-modeling, recommender-system

Let's say that I have two recommendation system models built,  Model A and Model B.

Now I track the performance of both the models for 5 days from 1st Jan to 5th Jan.

Each model has been assigned a different number of users to test the performance each day.

We capture metrics like as shown below.

Now, how can I know which model performs better?

[image]

Comment: what are the criteria you have for performance? If these are defined then the metrics of each system will point out the best

Comment: HI Nikos, thanks for the response. So, should I just say that based on Average profit Margin, Model B is better?. Am I right in saying that from the above data? What are some of the other criteria do you think might be useful? Can write as an amswer? I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: I fail to understand what your metrics mean, I lack the context plus I fail to understand the abbreviations used.